# Export .mdf to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am on a shared hosting plan and cannot install SQL Server Express, is there another way I can use my .mdf database or will I need to export it to a SQL Server database and change all my connection strings?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MDF file, the only way to access the information within it is through some type of SQL Server instance. You're going to have to use the [ATTACH mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) to add the .mdf to the instance. From there, you can query it as needed. From the sounds of things, you're going to have to modify where and how you connect, yes.